# How to call sync methods from other module In the form of async method in Discord.py?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py, python-asyncio

I want to use [Python Twitch API](https://pytwitchapi.readthedocs.io/en/v2.3.0/index.html) module completely async in discord.py and if it is not possible or it will take a long time, please introduce the complete alternative async modules.

Comment: [`TwitchIO`](https://github.com/TwitchIO/TwitchIO)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asyncio` does not forbid the use of `sync` functions in the `async` function, so you can use your library inside discord.py events

```
import asyncio

# Synchronous function
def say_sync(string):
  print(string)

# Asynchronous function
async def async_function():
  say_sync("Hello")
  await asyncio.sleep(1) # Sleep for 1 second
  say_sync("world!")

asyncio.run(async_function()) # Run async function
```

[Live Example](https://replit.com/@mrzencore/AsynchronousFunctionTest)